# dns txt record with out record name?

Tags: dns, dkim

My domain name provides dns hosting my domain.

But for txt record they dont have in put field for txt record name, there is only field for txt record value

My previous dns server that I manage my self, I was doing google._domainkey as record name

Is there a way to have valid dkim entry in txt with out record name?

Thanks

Comment: txt record are with descriptive purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DKIM needs a TXT record for the name "default._domainkey.your.fqdn.tld". If your DNS provider doesn't allow you to create that record, you may have to run your own DNS server or find another (commercial / free) DNS provider that does allow this record.

Comment: Do you know a free DNS provider with full control over DNS records? freedns.afraid.org doesn't let us change the name of a TXT record. Thus we can't use DKIM for our Google Apps.

Comment: With freedns.afraid.org one can use DKIM. For type TXT use the subdomain for, e.g. "selector._domainkey", which gives you "selector._domainkey.your.fqdn.tld".
I missunderstood  that the term "TXT record name" in some documentations actually is a subdomain.